# How to fire event when direction is entered within a custom area, using javascript google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I draw a area on the google map like this :

[image]

and also I draw direction between A point to B point like this :

[image]

now I want fire event when direction enter to custom area  and also fire event when direction exit from custom area

Comment: Any code snippet you tried and would like to share with us?

Comment: I use google maps drawing lib for draw area and use direction service to draw direction between A to B points , but I dont know how to determinate and fire event when direction enter and exit from area

Comment: Event?  Are you trying to determine when a person/car/device travelling on the route enters the circle?  Or just whether the route intersects with the circle?  Please provide your code as a [mcve] that demonstrates what you currently have.